# How to get only difference lines (non similar lines) of two log files in python

Tags: python, algorithm, file, automation, rpa

I have wrote program to compare two log files that has identical lines one is backup_file other is curr_file,
but in second files records are getting updated, once it gets updated I want to retrieve only the newly added lines from current file

in form of list like set difference

Example:

```
set1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
set2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
diff = set2 - set1

result:
 [6,7]`
```

Here is my code:

```
import filecmp
import shutil

if __name__ == '__main__':

    backup_file ="D:\PythonScripts\SIC_Automation\Backup.log" #backup_file for comparison with if the     current file have any updated entries
    curr_file= "D:\PythonScripts\SIC_Automation\Mock_files\FailedTid.log" #failed Transaction file from SIC


    with open(backup_file) as f1:
        backup_file_lines = set(f1.readlines())
    
    with open(curr_file) as f2:
        curr_file_lines = set(f2.readlines())

    if (not(filecmp.cmp(backup_file, curr_file))): 
        #1 get the diffence from the file and store in a variable
        diff_error_line = curr_file_lines - backup_file_lines

        print(diff_error_line) #Print the list of difference in logs- TEMP CODE
    else:
        print("Both files are identical")
```

**I have wrote code above is not working as I expect, below is file contents and what I am expecting**

First log file content:

```
2023-03-17 19:30:03,699 - Tid: AC19DD1D84856414D1F60001   Error: Input tax has been specified but there are no taxes to which it may be distributed. Please verify the details for this transaction.
2023-03-17 19:50:18,305 - Tid: AC19DD1D84856414D1F60001   Error: Input tax has been specified but there are no taxes to which it may be distributed. Please verify the details for this transaction.
2023-03-17 20:10:28,767 - Tid: AC19DD1D84856414D1F60001   Error: Input tax has been specified but there are no taxes to which it may be distributed. Please verify the details for this transaction.
```

second log file content:

```
2023-03-17 19:30:03,699 - Tid: AC19DD1D84856414D1F60001   Error: Input tax has been specified but there are no taxes to which it may be distributed. Please verify the details for this transaction.
2023-03-17 19:50:18,305 - Tid: AC19DD1D84856414D1F60001   Error: Input tax has been specified but there are no taxes to which it may be distributed. Please verify the details for this transaction.
2023-03-17 20:10:28,767 - Tid: AC19DD1D84856414D1F60001   Error: Input tax has been specified but there are no taxes to which it may be distributed. Please verify the details for this transaction.
2023-03-17 20:30:40,105 - Tid: AC19DD1D84856414D1F60001   Error: Input tax has been specified but there are no taxes to which it may be distributed. Please verify the details for this transaction.
```

**My expected output is** :

```
2023-03-17 20:30:40,105 - Tid: AC19DD1D84856414D1F60001   Error: Input tax has been specified but there are no taxes to which it may be distributed. Please verify the details for this transaction.
```

Comment: In what way is your code not working? When I run it with your sample input files, it generates your expected output.

Comment: Subtracting one set from the other (*set.difference*) should give you what you need. The only potential issue arises if the log files are very large as you have to have both loaded into memory concurrently

Comment: Oh thank you guys a big shout-out to you guys @larsks I figured It out where code was not working.

Comment: Oh thank you big shout-out to you @DarkKnight